# How to mock dependency injection with phpunit?

Tags: symfony, mocking, phpunit

I wish to test methods in this class:

```
class EmailerService
{
    protected $mailer;
    protected $router;
    protected $em;
    protected $emailMan;
    protected $emailReminderMan;
    protected $secret;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Swift_Mailer                                             $mailer
     * @param \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router            $router
     * @param \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager                               $em
     * @param EmailManager                                              $emailMan
     * @param EmailReminderManager                                      $emailReminderMan
     * @param                                                           $secret
     */
    public function __construct(Swift_Mailer $mailer, Router $router, EntityManager $em, EmailManager $emailMan, EmailReminderManager $emailReminderMan, $secret)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->emailMan = $emailMan;
        $this->emailReminderMan = $emailReminderMan;
        $this->secret = $secret;
    }
```

My test currently looks like this:

```
class EmailerServiceTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $emailer;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $mailer = $this->getMockBuilder('Swift_Mailer')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $router = $this->getMockBuilder('Router')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $em = $this->getMockBuilder('EntityManager')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $emailMan = $this->getMockBuilder('EmailManager')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $emailReminderMan = $this->getMockBuilder('EmailReminderManager')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $secret = '123';

        $this->emailer = new EmailerService($mailer, $router, $em, $emailMan, $emailReminderMan, $secret);
    }
```

But I get the error:

> 1)
>   T\CBundle\Tests\Service\EmailerServiceTest::testGetVariablesForModule
>   Argument 2 passed to T\CBundle\Service\EmailerService::__construct()
>   must be an instance of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router,
>   instance of Mock_Router_3e61717e given, called in ...

Also a bit confused why it triggers with Router, and not first with Swift_Mailer

Comment: what is `$router` into the second snippet of code?

Comment: @DonCallisto The correct files are imported/used at the top; Router specifically is Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router

Comment: `new EmailerService($mailer, $router, .... )` could you show us the declaration of `$router`? Moreover, could I know if `EmailerService` is registered as a service or is only a naming convention that you use?

Comment: Try with `$this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Bundle\Frameworkbundle\Routing\Router')`

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie: sorry, I didn't notice the code where you instantiate it ...

Comment: @Touki thanks, that's the answer, it's strings so I must use the FQN. If you answer I'll accept. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to use the real classname, otherwise PHPunit will just create a class named `Router` (note: this is *not* the expected `Symfony\Component\Routing\Router`):

```
     // don't need it here, Swift_Mailer is in the global scope
    $mailer = $this->getMockBuilder('Swift_Mailer')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $router = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $em = $this->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $emailMan = $this->getMockBuilder('Full\Namespace\To\EmailManager')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $emailReminderMan = $this->getMockBuilder('Full\Namespace\To\EmailReminderManager')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
```